No-brotli seems set in Apache but has no effect
Because I have to serve some files using PHP, I need to set the Content-Length header from PHP.
As I've found out, this can't work when Apache's compression is applied on top - obviously, as it changes the content size.
I've tried to set no-brotli depending on the request URI - and it does get set, but doesn't seem to change anything.
# apparently, this is needed to allow PHP to set Content-Length
SetEnv ap_trust_cgilike_cl 1 
SetEnvIf Request_URI backup/ no-gzip
SetEnvIf Request_URI backup/ no-brotli

Header always set X-Br "%{no-brotli}e"
Header always set X-BrRedir "%{REDIRECT_no-brotli}e"

# re-set env variables after redirect
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_no-gzip 1 no-gzip
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_no-brotli 1 no-brotli

RewriteRule ^(.*)$                index.php?key=$1 [L,nc,qsa]
# lots and lots of RewriteRules

Still, there is no Content-Length header. Looking at the headers, I see the following:
content-encoding: br
x-br: 1
x-brred: 1

From that, I come to the conclusion that the env gets set correctly (it seems to be set both before and after redirect), but Brotli is still compressing my output and thus preventing me from setting Content-Length.
Most likely - I think - the env does indeed NOT get set correctly - but where did I go wrong?
